# How do I leave orphaned rows in a @JoinTable for a @ManyToMany relationship in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have the following database schema

```
item
ID

batch
ID

batch_queue
ID

batch_item
FK_BatchID
FK_ItemID
```

and **both** entity classes for batch and batch_queue have the following field

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "batch_item",
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FK_BatchID") },
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ItemID") })
private List<Item> items;
```

When I delete a BatchQueue entity the rows in batch_item are considered orphaned and they get deleted too. I would like these rows to not be deleted so they can  be used by Batch entities.

(Note: batch_queue is essentially a subset of the batch table)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this as hibernate will only keep orphan child *entities* around. And rightly so as would you ask hibernate to break the FK property on `batch_item` you just declared in your code (both columns are FKs, but their respective key is gone).

Comment: I think you are right @mabi. I have taken the route of having two mapping tables to achieve what I wanted here. I think this is the only, and probably cleanest, way.